# Did we stop doing Myth of the month?

Tags: discussion, myth-of-the-month

Did we stop doing Myth of the month? Is it in somewhere else I don't know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People lost interest. It might be worth trying again. If we did, my advice is to choose stories that aren't longer than three or four pages: that way it would be less of a time commitment. Some of the previous stories were so long that I gave up halfway through.

If people were interested, I would be up for creating a new myth of a month around a (significantly) shorter story. Let me know in the comments/by voting on this answer if that's something people would be interested in.

Comment: Lets make an official announcement?

Comment: It might be easier to look at myths instead of epics, tales, etc. which contain myths. Less rigorous, less of a treasure-trove of information, but maybe on par with what many people here are looking for...